# I was offered a job but lied about finishing my degree

Tags: resume

So in my last few years of college my dad was diagnosed with cancer and I dropped out to take care of him.
I ended up working in a different field and I am really good at it, I've learned everything on the job.

I just got an offer but know I won't pass the education verification check, so I declined the offer. They came back to me asking me to reconsider.

Should I come clean and see if they still want to hire me? Or should I not respond and just stick with the job I have ?

Comment: I don't understand what your rationale is for lying on your resume. You knew from the start that this is easily verified, didn't you? And if you already have work experience, I'll break the news to you: Nobody cares about your college degree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lied on resume about obtaining a Bachelor degree](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111648/lied-on-resume-about-obtaining-a-bachelor-degree)

Comment: When/ where did you lie, exactly?

Comment: Once you've declined their offer, change your resume to reflect that you studied towards a degree but it remains unfinished. The education you have completed does matter, just don't lie about finishing it.

Comment: @jwsc not necessarily true, it highly depends on the employer and industry. I've known people who were very good at their job but were passed over for employment and promotion opportunities simply because they didn't have the academic credentials to go with it.

Comment: @SethR it is highly employer and industry specific (e.g., if you are a practicing physician at a hospital but you lied about graduating medical school then you will be fired when found out), but in general nobody cares.

Comment: In many jurisdictions, including the UK, Australia, Canada, and the US, making a false statement in a job application related to academic achievements is a criminal offence and you can be prosecuted for fraud. British people have gone to jail for it. The falsehood could be a degree you don't have, a higher grade degree than the one you have, or even high school certificates or grades. You don't even need to get the job to be prosecuted.

Answer (score 25):

> Should I come clean and see if they still want to hire me? Or should I not respond and just stick with the job I have.

Do neither.

Coming clean would likely brand you as a liar for this company and would likely make difficult any time spent with the company if by some chance they still hire you.  Also, depending on your industry, word of your lie can easily spread and hurt your opportunities with other companies.

Not responding is unprofessional behavior.

What you should do is respectfully decline their offer, thank them for their time, and apologize for any inconvenience you may have caused.  Take this experience as a lesson learned for your future job searches.  Do not lie about your education and experience.

Comment: let's say after he decline the hirer still asks to reconsider, then you reject it and explaining the real situation and why you rejected the offer because of said cause? 
Is this course of action still bad?

Comment: @encryptoferia If the company continues to push after being politely declined twice, they're being impolite and OP is under no obligation to entertain them.

Answer (score 10):

If you tell them that you lied on in your previous communication, you're unlikely to be offered a job. But there's still a chance, and you they're clearly somewhat desperate to hire. It's not a great way to start a relationship, but unless you think it's the kind of industry where you'll get blacklisted, you don't have too much to lose.

On the other hand, if you just ignore them then they'll think that you're rude or uninterested, and you *definitely* won't get the job.

Answer (score 10):

> Should I come clean and see if they still want to hire me?

You have absolutely nothing to lose by being completely honest starting right now.

Come clean. Let them know that you lied. Inform them of the conditions surrounding your leaving school. If you plan to finish school at some point, let them know that - but only if it's true.

The worst that happens is that they reject you. Frankly, if I was the hiring manager, that's what I would do. Sorry, but I can't trust someone who lied from the start.

The best that happens is they look past the lie and hire you.

Either way, you won't know if you don't ask.

Answer (score 2):

If your original application had said 'partially completed degree', and you were the best person for the job, you'd get the job.

It sounds like you claimed to have completed the degree, when you hadn't. In that case, you aren't going to get the job, because you lied. In most industries, lying is big no-no.

Thank them for their time, and move on. Be honest in your future dealings, and (maybe) even consider going back to complete the degree if you completed most of it.